# QGIS Insert statistical graph based on visible datapoints into layout

Tags: python, pyqgis

QGIS version 3.22.10-Białowieża

I have a large point vector dataset, each point has a variable has many variables. I am generating a bunch of figures with the layout tool and would like to include a figure on statistics (e.g. distribution) for the subset of the data shown in a particular figure. In my situation it is the windrose in blue shown in the figure below.

[image: Sample Figure with windrose in the lower right corner]

Currently, I have a Python script that creates the wind rose. In this method I read the file into a geopandas dataframe, filter it to match the data shown in the figure, and produce the figure using a python package. I save the figure as a .png. This all happens outside of QGIS on different python installation. Finally I include the .png in the QGIS layout as an image.

I need a way to automate this processes. Can I use the qgis python interpreter to run the code I have automatically? What method would you recommend?

Comment: What is the output of your python script windrose? Is it a dataset? Or is it a graphic?

Comment: Currently it is a .png output but I have a lot of flexibility here. Right now I load the .png output as an image into the layout. But I have to manually subset the data and run the python script...

Comment: Is it a windrose for each data point? or an aggregated windrose for the subset?

Comment: Aggregated windrose of all data in the subset

Comment: ok have a go at editing the question, cause the mods have closed it for not having enough detail. try adding some screen captures of the layout etc, and put the detail we discussed here in the comments and make it really specific what your stumbling block is.

Comment: Thanks nr_aus. This is my first time asking a question on stack sites